# Seeing X for values in one module

Tags: verilog, fpga

I have two modules 'wired' together. One is a simple sequence detector and one is a counter.

Here are the two signatures of the methods:

```
module Detector1010 (input [3:0] co_in, input j, clk, rst, output w, output reg init, output reg en);
module counter (input clk, rst, en, init, output reg [3:0] co );
```

Essentially that output register 'co' in the counter is intended to be readable from the Dector1010 module (hence the co_in) variable. The reason for that is I want to be able to detect when the co reaches a certain value, to perform some sort of action.

Within 'Detector1010' there is always block which checks the value of 'co_in'

```
$display("sleep! %d", co_in);
if(co_in == 4'b1111) begin
 //reached 16!
 $display("reached 16!");
end
```

Here I am just waiting for the counter value to reach 16 and printing what it is each time the always block executes. (How often does that execute? It seems to run just constantly and not on a clock.. I guess the whole point is its always running?). However by display instead prints:

```
"sleep! x"
```

As if the actual value of that register does not get passed in. I was using a wire to connect the two modules, so I thought this sort of input is allowed:

```
wire [3:0] co;
 wire init;
 wire en;
 assign co = 4'b0000;
 Detector1010 det(co, j, clk, rst, w, init, en);
 counter cnt(clk, rst, en, init, co);
```

as I figured the 'co' variable would just work as a databus between the detector and the counter modules. I guess I am misunderstanding how that variable works? Not really sure what I am doing wrong here!

I can post the whole code example. I was trying to just keep it concise.

Answer (score 0):

You have contention on the `co` signal which results in `x`.  Remove this line:

```
assign co = 4'b0000;
```

Your `counter` module drives the `co` output signal, but your testbench continually drives it to 0, at all times starting at time 0.  `co` would normally be initialized inside the `counter` module.